# how to check thread is running

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I want to check which thread is working/running.. As 5 thread are working/running then need to pause then-> as 1 is released/complete/stop next queued thread will start/running.

How to do this

Comment: Can't you keep track inside your program of which thread was currently released to work?

Comment: Generally you write your algorithms so you don't need to check the state of a thread.  It is only useful for detecting bugs in your application and is rarely done. If you think you need to do this its highly likely there is a better way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get what state a thread is in by using the getState() method which returns an Enum of Thread.States. A thread can only be in one of the following states at a given point in time.

**NEW** A Fresh thread that has not yet started to execute. 
**RUNNABLE** A thread that is executing in the Java virtual machine. 
**BLOCKED** A thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock. 
**WAITING** A thread that is wating to be notified by another thread. 
**TIMED_WAITING** A thread that is wating to be notified by another thread for a specific amount of time. 
**TERMINATED** A thread whos run method has ended.

```
Thread t = new Thread();
Thread.State e = t.getState();
Thread.State[] ts = e.values(); 
  for(int i = 0; i < ts.length; i++){
   System.out.println(ts[i]); 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use thread pool that is part of JDK, such as [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).